# JS/jQuery Alert if text field contains string

Tags: jquery, indexof

I have a text field (id=#CAT_Custom_244677) that is populated using a JS date picker. If the user chooses a date that results in a field value that contains '2013', I want to show an alert. Can't get this to work:

```
$('#CAT_Custom_244677').change(function() {
    if ( $(this).val().indexOf("2013") > -1 ) {
        alert("Yes");
    };
});
```

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/2HMvW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me, Try using `keydown` or `keyup` for it to trigger immediately after input:

```
<input type="text" id="CAT_Custom_244677" />

$('#CAT_Custom_244677').change(function() {
   if ( $(this).val().indexOf("2013") > -1 ) {
    alert("Yes");
   };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTgn9/

**Using keyup:**

```
$('#CAT_Custom_244677').keyup(function() {
   if ( $(this).val().indexOf("2013") > -1 ) {
    alert("Yes");
   };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTgn9/1/

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, but I think it's because my datepicker isn't firing an event. Clearly, your JSFiddle works. I just got rid of my date picker. Thanks-

Comment: @user1984577 - no worries. Maybe posting another question as to why your date picker isn't firing may help you understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `blur` event might work, depending on what datepicker is being used.  (Works for JQuery datepicker).